# Pointers changing eachother despite being unrelated

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am trying to use the Simplex Downhill method for finding the minimum of a function. I take three points as arrays of two values and assign each a pointer so that I can order them high-to-low according to their output of some function (Rosenbrock's parabolic valley in this case). After ordering these pointers I attempt to update the arrays with the respective values, however both the high and medium point take the same value unless the points were already in the correct order.

I set the three arrays and their respective pointers,

```
double plarray[] = {0., 0.};
double pmarray[] = {2., 0.};
double pharray[] = {0., 2.};
double *pl, *pm, *ph;
pl = &plarray[0], pm = &pmarray[0], ph = &pharray[0];
```

and sort the pointers as above. This bit works well, however when I try to replace the arrays with the proper values using this function,

```
void update(double x[], double *y){
    x[0] = *y;
    x[1] = *(y+1);
}
```

both `pmarray` and `pharray` take on the same values. I've tried swapping them around but it doesn't seem to change anything. Interestingly, `plarray` seems to work perfectly fine regardless of update order.

`Brop` (array of pointers sorted from lowest to highest in terms of their Brock output) is sorted as such where `brockop` points to Brock.  `sortSize` sorts the pointers given by the given function,

```
brop = sortSize(pl, pm, ph,  brockop);

double ** sortSize(double * p1p, double * p2p, double * p3p, double (func)(double *)){
    
    static double * order[3];
    double bp1 = func(p1p);
    double bp2 = func(p2p);
    double bp3 = func(p3p);
    double brocks[] = {bp1, bp2, bp3};
    
    order[2] = ((bp1 > bp2 && bp1 > bp3)? p1p: (bp2 > bp3)? p2p:p3p);
    order[0] = ((bp1 < bp2 && bp1 < bp3)? p1p: (bp2 < bp3)? p2p:p3p);
    order[1] = ((bp1 != func(order[0]) && bp1 != func(order[2]))? p1p: (bp2 != func(order[0]) && bp2 != func(order[2]))? p2p: p3p);
    
    return order;
}
```

I then assign the pointers to the sorted values in `brop`,

```
pl = *brop;
pm = *(brop + 1);
ph = *(brop + 2);
```

Please note that `brop` is an array of the pointers to the points of the function I wanted to sort, not a point itself.

I have some output after adding a bunch of `printf` for debugging,

```
y of Brop[0], (0.000000, 0.000000) = 1.000000
y of Brop[1], (-1.000000, 1.500000) = 29.000000
y of Brop[2], (0.000000, 2.000000) = 401.000000
--------Before assigning to Brop values--------
P_h pointer: -1.000000, 1.500000, yh = 29.000000
P_m pointer: 0.000000, 2.000000, ym = 401.000000
P_l pointer: 0.000000, 0.000000, yl = 1.000000
--------Array values before assigning to brop ------
P_h array: -1.000000, 1.500000, yh = 29.000000
P_m array: 0.000000, 2.000000, ym = 401.000000
P_l array: 0.000000, 0.000000, yl = 1.000000
-------Pointers asigned to brop values-----
P_h pointer: 0.000000, 2.000000, yh = 401.000000
P_m pointer: -1.000000, 1.500000, ym = 29.000000
P_l pointer: 0.000000, 0.000000, yl = 1.000000
--------Array values after assigning to brop-------
P_h array: -1.000000, 1.500000, yh = 29.000000
P_m array: 0.000000, 2.000000, ym = 401.000000
P_l array: 0.000000, 0.000000, yl = 1.000000
------------P_m updated--------
P_h pointer: -1.000000, 1.500000, yh = 29.000000
P_m pointer: -1.000000, 1.500000, ym = 29.000000
P_l pointer: 0.000000, 0.000000, yl = 1.000000
------------P_h updated--------
P_h pointer: -1.000000, 1.500000, yh = 29.000000
P_m pointer: -1.000000, 1.500000, ym = 29.000000
P_l pointer: 0.000000, 0.000000, yl = 1.000000
----------Arrays updated-----------
P_h: -1.000000, 1.500000, yh = 29.000000
P_m: -1.000000, 1.500000, ym = 29.000000
P_l: 0.000000, 0.000000, yl = 1.000000
```

Code used to produce debug output:

```
printf("--------Before assigning to Brop values--------\n");
        printf("P_h pointer: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", *ph, *(ph+1), Brock(ph));
        printf("P_m pointer: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", *pm, *(pm+1), Brock(pm));
        printf("P_l pointer: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", *pl, *(pl+1), Brock(pl));
        printf("--------Array values before assigning to brop ------\n");
        printf("P_h array: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", pharray[0], pharray[1], BrockNP(pharray));
        printf("P_m array: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", pmarray[0], pmarray[1], BrockNP(pmarray));
        printf("P_l array: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", plarray[0], plarray[1], BrockNP(plarray));
        pl = *brop;
        pm = *(brop + 1);
        ph = *(brop + 2);
        printf("-------Pointers asigned to brop values-----\n");
        printf("P_h pointer: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", *ph, *(ph+1), Brock(ph));
        printf("P_m pointer: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", *pm, *(pm+1), Brock(pm));
        printf("P_l pointer: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", *pl, *(pl+1), Brock(pl));
        printf("--------Array values after assigning to brop-------\n");
        printf("P_h array: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", pharray[0], pharray[1], BrockNP(pharray));
        printf("P_m array: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", pmarray[0], pmarray[1], BrockNP(pmarray));
        printf("P_l array: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", plarray[0], plarray[1], BrockNP(plarray));
        
        update(pmarray, *(brop + 1));
        
        printf("------------P_m updated--------\n");
        printf("P_h pointer: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", *ph, *(ph+1), Brock(ph));
        printf("P_m pointer: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", *pm, *(pm+1), Brock(pm));
        printf("P_l pointer: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", *pl, *(pl+1), Brock(pl));
        update(pharray, *(brop+2));
        printf("------------P_h updated--------\n");
        printf("P_h pointer: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", *ph, *(ph+1), Brock(ph));
        printf("P_m pointer: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", *pm, *(pm+1), Brock(pm));
        printf("P_l pointer: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", *pl, *(pl+1), Brock(pl));
        update(plarray, *brop);
        printf("----------Arrays updated-----------\n");
        printf("P_h: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", *ph, *(ph+1), Brock(ph));
        printf("P_m: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", *pm, *(pm+1), Brock(pm));
        printf("P_l: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", *pl, *(pl+1), Brock(pl));
        printf("after sorting\n");
```

Function used for y-values:

```
double Brock(double * vec){
    return 100*pow(*(vec+1) - ((*vec)*(*vec)), 2) + pow(1 - *vec, 2);
}
```

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double BrockNP(double x[]){
    return 100*pow(x[1] - (x[0]*x[0]), 2) + pow(1 - x[0], 2);
}   
double Brock(double * vec){
    return 100*pow(*(vec+1) - ((*vec)*(*vec)), 2) + pow(1 - *vec, 2);
}

double ** sortSize(double * p1p, double * p2p, double * p3p, double (func)(double *));
void update(double x[], double *y);

int main(){
    
    double *pl, *pm, *ph;
    double **brop;
    double (*brockop)(double *);
    
    double plarray[] = {0., 0.};
    double pmarray[] = {2., 0.};
    double pharray[] = {0., 2.};
    
    pl = &plarray[0], pm = &pmarray[0], ph = &pharray[0];
    brockop = &Brock;
        
    brop = sortSize(pl, pm, ph,  brockop);
    
    printf("--------Before assigning to Brop values--------\n");
    printf("P_h pointer: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", *ph, *(ph+1), Brock(ph));
    printf("P_m pointer: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", *pm, *(pm+1), Brock(pm));
    printf("P_l pointer: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", *pl, *(pl+1), Brock(pl));
    printf("--------Array values before assigning to brop ------\n");
    printf("P_h array: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", pharray[0], pharray[1], BrockNP(pharray));
    printf("P_m array: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", pmarray[0], pmarray[1], BrockNP(pmarray));
    printf("P_l array: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", plarray[0], plarray[1], BrockNP(plarray));
    
    pl = *brop;
    pm = *(brop + 1);
    ph = *(brop + 2);
    
    printf("-------Pointers asigned to brop values-----\n");
    printf("P_h pointer: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", *ph, *(ph+1), Brock(ph));
    printf("P_m pointer: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", *pm, *(pm+1), Brock(pm));
    printf("P_l pointer: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", *pl, *(pl+1), Brock(pl));
    printf("--------Array values after assigning to brop-------\n");
    printf("P_h array: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", pharray[0], pharray[1], BrockNP(pharray));
    printf("P_m array: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", pmarray[0], pmarray[1], BrockNP(pmarray));
    printf("P_l array: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", plarray[0], plarray[1], BrockNP(plarray));

    update(pmarray, *(brop + 1));      //This seems to set pharray and pmarray to the same array
    printf("------------P_m updated--------\n");
    printf("P_h pointer: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", *ph, *(ph+1), Brock(ph));
    printf("P_m pointer: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", *pm, *(pm+1), Brock(pm));
    printf("P_l pointer: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", *pl, *(pl+1), Brock(pl));
    
    update(pharray, *(brop+2));
    printf("------------P_h updated--------\n");
    printf("P_h pointer: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", *ph, *(ph+1), Brock(ph));
    printf("P_m pointer: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", *pm, *(pm+1), Brock(pm));
    printf("P_l pointer: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", *pl, *(pl+1), Brock(pl));
    
    update(plarray, *brop);
    printf("----------Arrays updated-----------\n");
    printf("P_h: %lf, %lf, yh = %lf\n", *ph, *(ph+1), Brock(ph));
    printf("P_m: %lf, %lf, ym = %lf\n", *pm, *(pm+1), Brock(pm));
    printf("P_l: %lf, %lf, yl = %lf\n", *pl, *(pl+1), Brock(pl));
    printf("after sorting\n");    
    
    return 0;
}
        
double ** sortSize(double * p1p, double * p2p, double * p3p, double (func)(double *)){
    
    static double * order[3];
    double bp1 = func(p1p);
    double bp2 = func(p2p);
    double bp3 = func(p3p);
    double brocks[] = {bp1, bp2, bp3};
    
    order[2] = ((bp1 > bp2 && bp1 > bp3)? p1p: (bp2 > bp3)? p2p:p3p);
    order[0] = ((bp1 < bp2 && bp1 < bp3)? p1p: (bp2 < bp3)? p2p:p3p);
    order[1] = ((bp1 != func(order[0]) && bp1 != func(order[2]))? p1p: (bp2 != func(order[0]) && bp2 != func(order[2]))? p2p: p3p);
    
    return order;
}

void update(double x[], double *y){
    x[0] = *y;
    x[1] = *(y+1);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: brop is just the array of pointers in size order as above.

Comment: You need to provide a full [mre] - there's too much missing here

Comment: There are 3 elements used in `Brop` but only 2 vlaues in the other arrays. It's not clear what is happening.

Comment: You need to _show_ us Brop, and what you are doing with the pointers.

Comment: Showing debug output without showing the code that generates the debug output is useless to us.

Comment: @UnholySheep Right - thank you for the heads up, hopefully I've added enough.

Comment: @IanAbbott I've added the output code now. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Max I've added the code for Brop and the pointers, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've provided info for Brop and context on why they differ - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you but the post is still a hotch-potch of disconnected snippets. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. That means code that can be compiled exactly as given, to replicate the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah I see, will do that now. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: I think there is enough code in `sortSize` to work out where the problem is now. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Note that your `Brock()` and `BrockNP()` functions are *exactly* equivalent to each other.  In particular, if "NP" is supposed to stand for "non-pointer", then do be aware that `BrockNP()`'s parameter `x` is declared as a pointer, even though it may not look that way.

Comment: It's weird that `sortSize()` re-runs `func` when choosing a value for `order[1]`.  If it wants to choose the pointer that has not yet been assigned, then why not compare the pointer values *directly*, instead of recomputing corresponding values of `func()` and comparing those?  Comparing the pointers directly would avoid issues in the event that `func()` computes identical values for two or all three of the inputs.

Comment: Yeah, the OP doesn't seem to realize that `*(p+i)` is exactly the same as `p[i]`.

Comment: The code seems like proper obfuscation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we simplify your code down to the absolute minimum (using just two doubles instead of three arrays), you'll see that you do the equivalent of this:

```
double x = 42, y = 43;
double *px = &y, *py = &x; // !! notice that these are swapped !!
x = *px; // A
y = *py; // B
```

Line A here overwrites the value of `x`. So even though `py` points to `x`, the original value of `x` is already lost, so `y` will be set to 43 because that's what's stored in `x` when the code reaches line B.

There are multiple ways to solve this:

- create a copy of your three arrays, apply the permutation, and then copy back,
- sort your points in-place by swapping values between the three arrays in your sort function, or
- always use the pointers `pl`, `pm`, `ph` instead of the original arrays. So you won't need to copy things around at all.

The first is probably the simplest fix to the existing code:

```
double plarray[] = {0., 0.};
double pmarray[] = {2., 0.};
double pharray[] = {0., 2.};

// ... sort ...

pl = brop[0];
pm = brop[1];
ph = brop[2];
double tmp_plarray[2];
double tmp_pmarray[2];
double tmp_pharray[2];

// apply permutation into temporary arrays
update(tmp_plarray, pl);
update(tmp_pmarray, pm);
update(tmp_pharray, ph);

// copy back into original arrays
update(plarray, tmp_plarray);
update(pmarray, tmp_pmarray);
update(pharray, tmp_pharray);
```

Though I'd recommend going with the 3rd as it will simplify a lot of your code greatly while simultaneously being faster.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Funnily enough I originally did only use the pointers but eventually convinced myself that pointers were the root cause and I just couldn't see why, so I made the change to arrays. It's my first time with C so I appreciate the clear answer, thanks again.